# How do I set bits to 0 with boolean arithmetic?

Tags: assembly, 6502

Still new to bitwise operations in 6502 assembly.  I would like to have a byte that
has 8 flags.  This will store the status of my meta-sprite.

I want to be able to set specific flags without altering the others.

I know how to use ORA to set them to one:

```
  lda status
  ora #%00000001 ; set bit 0 to true
  sta status
```

I know how to use EOR to toggle them:

```
  lda status
  eor #%00000001 ; if bit 0 = true, then bit 0 = false and vise versa
  sta status
```

Lastly, I know how to check if a bit is true:

```
  lda status
  and #%00000001 ; if bit 0 = true then set overflow flag to true
```

But how to set a specific flag to 0, without altering any others?  Even if I used
AND, how would I force it to set the desired bit to 0?

Thanks, I'm sure I'm missing something simple.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about

```
lda status
and #%11111110 ; set bit 0 to false
sta status
```

Note that all other bits are not touched, since `1 AND X` is always `X` for every bit. Only bit 0 changes since `0 AND X` is always `0`.

Comment: Thank you.  I knew it was simple, I must have missed that in my documents.

Comment: You probably meant "and", not "eor".

Comment: If you're feeling adventurous, you can also use the undocumented opcode 'SAX' to combine the AND / STA instructions. Presupposing .X contains your bitmask and .A the status byte (or vice-versa) SAX is a slick way of doing the AND, storing the result, and leaving the CPU status flags unchanged.

Comment: Please don't use undocumented opcodes...ever.  Your code will crash a 65816.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with 6502 specifically, but to clear a bit you generally AND with a value that has every bit set except the one you want to clear.